# Oscillations on the surface of a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm solving for the trajectory of particle on a sphere that has the orbit shown in the image I have attached below.

Clearly it is oscillating on the sphere, but it does not cover the whole sphere. I have found the correct frequencies that characterize the oscillations, but I am not sure what the form of the solution should look like.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated in trying to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you post any equations or anything more concrete?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to help you just by looking at the image. I would try with something of the form
$$\pmatrix{\varphi(t)\\\theta(t)} = \pmatrix{t\\A\sin(Bt)}$$
for some real numbers $A,B>0$, where $\varphi$ is the angle in the $yz$-plane (i.e. the longitude), and $\theta$ is the latitude. In cartesian coordinates, this gives
$$\pmatrix{x(t)\\y(t)\\z(t)} = \pmatrix{\sin(A\sin(Bt))\\\cos(A\sin(Bt)\cos(t)\\\cos(A\sin(Bt)\sin(t)}.$$